# jsoup getelementsbytag get the html elements high in the hierarchy only

Tags: java, jsoup

I have to parse some HTML from a website which I cannot change. I am using Jsoup.

Here is some html:

```
<th></th>
<td> <!-- <td> tags on a high level in the hierarchy. -->
  <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td></td> <!-- <td> tags on a low level in the hierarchy. -->
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

I wanted to do `elementname.getElemementsByTag("td");` but this method gets all `<td>` tags, but I only want to get the `<td>` tags on the high level in the hierarchy and skip the ones on the lower level in the hierarchy. Does anyone know how to do that?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsoup allows you to get elements through CSS selectors by `document.selector("CSS SELECTOR")`.

If you want direct `td` chilren of a `table` you can use the [CSS selector `>`, which means direct children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). For your case, then, you should use:

```
#tableID > tbody > tr > td
```

This gets you all first-level `td`s of the `#tableID` `table`. Some things to notice:

- You **have** to include `> tbody > tr` in the middle. Even if your original HTML markup does not have them, Jsoup will create them when parsing the HTML.
- You don't need to have an ID at the first part. You can have anything. For example, all first level `td`s of all `table`s with class `.pretty`: `table.pretty > tbody > tr > td`.

In Jsoup:

- `Elements tds = document.select("#tableID > tbody > tr > td");`
- Or, if you want to select the table first (or have selected it before):

  - `Element myTable = document.select("#tableID")`;
  - `Elements tds = myTable.select(" > tbody > tr > td")`;

**Last but not least, an example code getting the `TD`s from your example:**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class JsoupHtmlDirectChildren {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "" +
                "<html>                                                                  " +
                "  <body>                                                                " +
                "    <span>HELLO!</span>                                                 " +
                "    <table id=\"myTable\">                                              " +
                "      <tbody>                                                           " +
                "        <tr>                                                            " +
                "          <th>header</th>                                               " +
                "          <!-- <td> tags on a high level in the hierarchy. -->          " +
                "          <td>high level1                                               " +
                "            <table>                                                     " +
                "              <tbody>                                                   " +
                "                <tr>                                                    " +
                "                  <!-- <td> tags on a low level in the hierarchy. -->   " +
                "                  <td>low level1</td>                                   " +
                "                  <td>low level2</td>                                   " +
                "                  <td>low level3</td>                                   " +
                "                </tr>                                                   " +
                "              </tbody>                                                  " +
                "            </table>                                                    " +
                "          </td>                                                         " +
                "          <td>high level2</td>                                          " +
                "          <td>high level3</td>                                          " +
                "        </tr>                                                           " +
                "      </tbody>                                                          " +
                "    </table>                                                            " +
                "  </body>                                                               " +
                "</html>                                                                 ";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        // all first level children TD of the #myTable table
        Elements highLevelTDs = doc.select("#myTable > tbody > tr > td");
        System.out.println("QUANTITY FOUND: "+highLevelTDs.size());
        for (Element td : highLevelTDs) {
            System.out.println("\n\n###HIGH LEVEL TD: "+td);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
QUANTITY FOUND: 3

###HIGH LEVEL TD: <td>high level1 
 <table> 
  <tbody> 
   <tr> 
    <!-- <td> tags on a low level in the hierarchy. --> 
    <td>low level1</td> 
    <td>low level2</td> 
    <td>low level3</td> 
   </tr> 
  </tbody> 
 </table> </td>

###HIGH LEVEL TD: <td>high level2</td>

###HIGH LEVEL TD: <td>high level3</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the site you are looking at has detailed HTML markup rather than the one you showed us here.

If your Tag's have descriptors such as class or ID or other attributes, they can be used to filter the respective `Elements` you are interested in.

For eg. to get all the `<td>` elements with class attribute "high" you can do something like this.

```
Elemenets highTDElements = rootElementName.select("td.high");
```

More details on the selector syntax is available on the [official site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), but this will be useful only when there are descriptors such as attributes/IDs/Class etc.

Otherwise you are limited by DOM traversal and you should really know where exactly the element resides.

Comment: That's the whole problem. This website has not so much detailed markup. Some have a class attribute, other's don't. This won't really help me. Anyway, thank you very much for your effort, I appreciate it.